# Pentaho Kettle (Spoon) - Delete Records From Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to delete records in my target table based on whether records exist in source table. I tried using a 'Delete' step, but I noticed that this step is based on a conditional clause.

My condition is quite simple "if the record/row does NOT exist in table A [source], delete the record/row from table B [destination]".

I also read about using a 'Merge Rows (diff)' step, but it seems to check/compare the entire set of tables for differences.

The table has several million records with many hundreds of columns in a MySQL server, I need to do this in the most efficient way.
I'm doing a search of table A with the Table input object and sql command:
'' ' `SELECT I went , user , password , attribute , op FROM viewuserradiusunisulma`

Any help would be appreciated.

print - image screen pentaho transformation

[Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcDbc.png)

[Delete Pentaho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bT5w.png)

Comment: Image print:
1-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/boGVm.png
2-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BNLP.png

Answer (score 0):

if your source and target table are in the same database, you can use a SQL query to delete all records in tableB that don't have a corresponding entry in tableA:

```
delete tableB where not exists (select id from tableA where id = tableB.id)
```

if source and destination tables are not in the same database, you would have to go through all rows in tableB and check whether the record exists in tableA. If your source tableA has a limited number of rows, loading the key values in memory and then performing a stream lookup instead of a database lookup would be much faster. I'd probably try that even with higher number of rows because of the significant performance impact.

**note**: I hope I haven't messed up the sql syntax, I'm thinking almost exclusively in abap at the moment and that messes with my memory a bit. So please test this on some backup before firing away.

Comment: Dirk Trilsbeek I'm sorry. I do not know how to do it. Can you explain better to me how to do this in pentaho. I'm studying Pentaho by myself and it's complex.
Tables are in different databases. Table A - I created a view and it is stored in a database named student and another table B in another database named authentication

Comment: I don't have a PDI setup available right now to create screen shots. The slow version would be a table input for table B, then a database lookup for the key fields in table A, selecting a field from table A that is never empty in that table, then a switch or filter to remove all the rows you don't want to delete (where the field from table A you selected isn't empty) and then the step to delete the remaining rows row by row. It's going to be slow, because it will create several queries per row. But it's easier to create than a setup with a second table input and a stream lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In this case, I check the records, then report, update and enter the new data

[Trasnsformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUfiA.png)